# Do SOQL queries of Tooling API objects count against governor limits?

Tags: governorlimits, tooling-api

The "system catalog" objects of the Tooling API (EntityDefinition, FieldDefinition, etc) provide a lightweight alternative to describe() calls, for example:

```
// get a list of fields for an sObject
list<FieldDefinition> fields = [
    select QualifiedApiName 
      from FieldDefinition
     where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = :sObjectName];
```

But do such queries count against governor limits?  Describe limits were removed in Summer '14.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear so; the following code fails the assertion:

```
// do SOQL queries against Tooling API objects count towards query limits?
string sObjectName = 'Account';
integer q = Limits.getQueries();
list<FieldDefinition> fds = [select QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = :sObjectName];
integer q2 = Limits.getQueries();
system.assertEquals(q, q2);
```

In the limits documentation, queries of Custom Metadata Types are explicitly listed as not being subject to query limits, and in fact replacing the ToolingAPI query with a query of a custom metadata type causes the assertion to pass - getQueries() doesn't change for an MDT query, but does change for a ToolingAPI query.

Comment: Seems like they should not: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cCaGAAU

Comment: You've got my vote!